# Charset omitted from content-type header

Tags: html, character-encoding

In my `<head>`, I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Because I'm seeing a couple of funky characters, I took a closer look at the `Content-Type` response header in Firebug (and Safari's inspector) and both read `Content-Type:text/html`. No indication that the charset is recognized. I'm using an HTML5 doctype and have also tried `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. Neither has worked or changed the value I see in the inspectors.

I'm assuming that both developer tools would report the accurate `Content-Type` including the charset, but I guess I've never had a reason to look all that closely. Is there anything else I should do to ensure that the page is rendered with the UTF8 character set?

I'm not sure this is my problem, but it seemed odd so I thought I'd ask. Maybe my expectations are incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: What do the funky characters look like?

Comment: The original character is an emdash. It's served as a "?" inside a filled triangle. If SO supported screenshots, I'd post one, but maybe the description will suffice.

Comment: that sounds like you're outputting UTF-8 all right, but your data is broken. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Yep, I just needed to isolate that fact. This is coming from a MySQL database. I specified the default charset in my .htaccess and confirmed that it's a data issue. Now my `Content-Type` header reads as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may not have been my problem, I "corrected" the `Content-Type` response header to appear as expected (with the charset attached) by including the Apache directive `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in my htaccess file.